# USB Security / Mounting / Authentication

Tags: usb, security, home-security, home-electronics

I have few questions regarding Pen-drive security.

1. Is there any way to, prevent a pen-drive, to stop detecting on random system. I want to detect my pen-drive on a particular system. Please, recommend a proper solution anything with software or hardware would be helpful.
2. Can we stop a pen-drive from being formatted without proper authentication. I have tried like all the software they are good but after formatting all data is lost.

Comment: I'm rather confused as to what you're asking. Are you trying to prevent a specific pen drive from being written to on all systems but one?

Comment: I want to make my pendrive detectable on basis of MAC address or IP address of host system. Suppose my host has a mac address of 00-01-0a. I will bind that Mac address with flash drive. When i will insert that flash drive onto host system. First, flash drive will verify the host MAC address. If its matched it will mounted on system and reveal its file system to the host. All i'm asking that is it feasible. Like making a flash drive detectable on a particular system with the help of software or hardware..

Comment: I guess that's probably possible, but I don't think the standard USB mass storage protocol allows for it; you're going to need something more complicated. Verification based on MAC addresses or IP addresses is also probably a bad way of doing things. As for existing products, I don't think there are any; most probably just use hardware encryption + password or biometric authentication, which if your situation allows for it, is probably what I'd recommend.